# Failed to swap azure website

Tags: azure, swap, azure-web-app-service

When swapping my production with my deployment slot I get the following error:

> Failed to swap website slot xxx-prod(xxx-prod-deployment-slot) with slot production:
>
> Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is not present or provided in an invalid format.

I'm not 100% sure that it ever worked for me, but I think it did.

Any Suggestion please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with the preview portal. It should be fixed soon. A work around would be to try the old portal for the swap, or the command line.

Comment: Thank you! Worked in the old portal. Any idea where I can see/follow fixed issues in the preview portal?

Comment: unfortunately I am not aware of any place to see these issues publicly.